Multiline log problem in AWS Elastic Beanstalk AL2023 with Node.js
I'm encountering an issue with my Node.js server running in an Elastic Beanstalk environment with the AL2023 platform for Node.js 20. When I attempt to log an object using console.log('here is the payload', {data: {message: 'hi'}});, it splits the log into multiple entries as shown below:
Apr 8 14:27:33 {ip} web[pid]: here is the payload {
Apr 8 14:27:33 {ip} web[pid]: data:{
Apr 8 14:27:33 {ip} web[pid]: message: 'hi'
Apr 8 14:27:33 {ip} web[pid]: }
Apr 8 14:27:33 {ip} web[pid]: }

However, I don't encounter this issue when using the AL1 platform for Node.js 10. Can someone please help me resolve this issue? I am currently using a custom method to serialise the object using JSON.stringify before printing it, but I'm concerned about the CPU overhead it incurs. Are there any alternative approaches to address this issue efficiently?
